# React components library with MUI font

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, storybook

I made a small library of React components but the problem is that I’m using Material UI. Material UI is using Roboto font which has to be linked to HTML head.

How can I export each React component with the Roboto font included?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can import Roboto inside any of your components like module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/roboto

```
import "@fontsource/roboto"; // Defaults to weight 400.
```

Also check official Material UI docs here
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-typography/#install-with-npm

Comment: I already did it and it doesn’t work. The font didn’t change.

Comment: I mean it doesn’t work when using components which are not Typography.

Comment: please provide example of such component and the way you are using material ui (also version). also the way you intend to use these components.

Comment: Sure.

That's how I want to export it and just import it somewhere with the font already included and works. Without always using the Typography component.
`import React from 'react';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';

export const HelloWorld = () => {
  const [click, setClick] = React.useState(0);

  return (
      <Box
        width='400px'
        height='400px'
        display='flex'
        alignItems='center'
        justifyContent='center'
        onClick={() => setClick(click + 1)}>
        {click}
      </Box>
  );
};
`

Comment: I guess wrapping all texts inside your custom components is the only way to "provide" the font-family: Roboto; css style to the element and its descendants.
Workaround for that could be <Box style={{fontFamily: "Roboto"}} or wrapping styled component for example with css styling : font-family: Roboto

Comment: Maybe provide codepen/sandbox for testing this one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my last comment above

I guess wrapping all texts inside your custom components is the only way to "provide" the font-family: Roboto; css style to the element and its descendants.
Workaround for that could be <Box style={{fontFamily: "Roboto"}} or wrapping styled component for example with css styling : font-family: Roboto

See example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-forest-x93th3?file=/src/hello.jsx

Comment: Sure, will check tomorrow and update.